# ChartJS and require: Chart is undefined

Tags: javascript, requirejs, chart.js

I am using requirejs for my project and it works well with other modules (jQuery, Handlebars, ...) but not with Chartjs.

Here is an example that fails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="scripts/libs/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['scripts/libs/chartjs/Chart.min'], function(Chart) {
        console.log("go"); // prints "go"
        console.log(Chart); // prints "undefined"
        var ctx = document.getElementById("test").getContext("2d"),
            chart = new Chart(ctx); // Throws a TypeError: Chart is not a constructor
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="test" width="200px" height="200px"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

The require.js and Chart.min.js are loaded fine but I cannot get ChartJS to work.

Here are the dependencies of my project in bower.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "select2": "^4.0.1",
    "select2-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "handlebars": "~4.0.5",
    "requirejs": "^2.2.0",
    "Chart.js": "^2.0.0"
  }
```

And the versions installed:

```
├── Chart.js#2.0.0
├─┬ bootstrap#3.3.6 (latest is 4.0.0-alpha.2)
│ └── jquery#2.2.0 (2.2.3 available, latest is 3.0.0-beta1)
├── handlebars#4.0.5
├── jquery#2.2.0 (2.2.3 available, latest is 3.0.0-beta1)
├── requirejs#2.2.0
├── select2#4.0.1 (4.0.2 available)
└── select2-bootstrap#1.3.0
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: do you have div with test id?

Comment: That's the canvas id.

Comment: put your script at bottom so it will access canvas below the canvas

Comment: let me know if there is problem

Comment: That's not the issue here. The ctx variable is fine and not undefined.

Comment: `require(['path/to/Chartjs'], function(Chart){
    var Chartjs = Chart.noConflict();
});` try this

Comment: Still getting the TypeError: Chart is undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109154/discussion-between-uzaif-and-lilorox).

Comment: did you check chartjs is loaded or not in your source with ctrl+u?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using v2.0 of Chart.js make sure you get a latest version (it worked for me with **2.0.0-beta2**, but not with alpha). Also, since Chart.js depends on **moment.js** you'll need to include that as well.

---

With older versions of Chart.js v2.0 (say alpha), you'll have to load Chart.js as a legacy script and use the global variable (or `noConflict()`).

---

The dependency on moment.js is not very obvious (related issue - https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/2110). Here's what you get on the console, when you load Chart.js as a normal script file.

[image]

When Chart.js is loaded by require.js, this dependency causes a request for moment.js.

Comment: Yes I am using v2.0.0. But the dependency to moment is not cited in the documentation :(

Comment: So just include moment.js too and a newer version of Chart.js v2.0 if you are using an older version and it should work (I just put moment.js in the root directory so that it was loaded automatically when requirejs identified it as a dependency)

Comment: I don't need momentjs and a quick try at it (by loading it side-by-side Chartjs in the require function) did not solve the issue so I went back to Chart.js 1.1.1 and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Oh nice, strange that it didn't work though - probably something to do with the order of loading. You are probably right on the documentation - I just noticed the moment.js dependency in the console.

Comment: I did not event have a message in the console. No error, nothing which is strange. But maybe this is hidden by requirejs or the fact that I'm not (yet) in strict mode?

Comment: This does not seem to work either actually. I filled a bug: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/2298

Comment: Excellent! Tried with using Chart v1 as legacy scripts?

Comment: Yes but as stated in the bug, I cannot seem to make it work with v1.1.1 either. Here are the fiddles: v2.0.2 -> https://jsfiddle.net/pa7x2ymq/ v1.1.1 -> https://jsfiddle.net/oL9gh6be/1/

Answer (score 0):

For those also sent here by google, I had to shim the file to export the correct variable:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts',
    paths: {
        ...
        'chartjs': 'vendor/Chart'
    },
    shim: { 
        'chartjs': {
            exports: 'Chart'
        }
    },
});
```